# About Mapping between entities in spring-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Working in spring-boot with spring-data and hibernate , I have an entity AppUser (it can be an Client or A devlopper , it dependes on the role of each one , so i have another entity role ..)

And an entity Intervention .

The AppUser(When he has role Client) he can add/delete one_to_many intervention.

The AppUser(When he has role devlopper) he can occupies by one_to_many of the intervention of Clients(he can validates or not an intervention ).

So as i have Only one *Entity AppUser* defined as below :

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String prenom;
    private String nom;
    private Long tel;
    private String cin;
    private String email ;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" )
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="appuser-intervention")
    private Collection<Intervention> interventions = new 
    ArrayList<Intervention>();



    public void addToInterventions(Intervention intervention){this.interventions.add(intervention);}

    public void addToRoles(AppRole role){this.roles.add(role);}

}
```

*Entity Intervention :*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Intervention implements Serializable {

            @Id @GeneratedValue
            private Long Id;

            private String objet;

            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
            private Date date;

            @Column(columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT false")
            private boolean valid;


            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
            @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-intervention")
            private AppUser appUser;

}
```

So as there is on_to_many between AppUser(Client,Devlopper) and intervention

do i need to add two List of intervention in appUser ?

And Also do i need to add Two object AppUser in entity Intervention ? (one for client and one for devlopper ) ?

Or only one list in AppUser and one object in intervention ?

Waiting for your help :) .

**EDIT**

```
            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
            @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-intervention")
            private AppUser appClient;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name ="Id_AppUser")
            @JsonBackReference("appuser-intervention")
            private AppUser appDevlopper ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define two lists for each user type for either developer or client. Rather declaring two lists you can provide role/userType in AppUser.

Comment: But in Entity intervention i need to store the appUser(Client) who made the intervention and at the same time the appUser(devlopper) who had validated the intervention . for exemple (idIntervention :1 , AppUser (created by) : Client1, AppUser(validated by) :Devlopper2 etc ... , For roles i have already implemented this (if this appUser is a client or a devlopper etc) .

Comment: You should keep it all in single join table rather separate join table for each role type

Comment: Can you please explain to me more ? For exemple while saving the user who created the intervention and the user who validate it.  How the request will be ?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view there are 2 ways:

1. Create different classes for developer and client(You still can keep them in one db table - just configure inheritance in hibernate)
2. You can keep one list inside AppUser and have 2 AppUser links in Intervention - one to developer who validated intervention, and client who made it.

Comment: I prefer the second method , i'have edited the post if you can take a look at it again :) , my question now is what about JoinColumn and jsonbackreference they should be the same for devlopper and client right ? as i have one list in AppUser .

Comment: If I understood correctly your Intervention entity can have both of them(developer and client) at the same time? If yes, you need have different join columns(client_id and developer_id, for example), the same for @JsonBackReference

Comment: Yes exactly, each intervention should be created at the same time by a client and validated by developer , but how different join column will refere the only one list in appUser ? Also for jsonbackreference

Comment: It actually the part of what Hibernate should do if you use it. I suppose it will look like that: You will have table `intervention` with these 2 columns: client_id and developer_id. And when AppUser.interventions will be selected, query like that will be triggered: SELECT * FROM intervention where client_id = ? OR developer_id = ?

Comment: Ah okey i see , so another question sorry  : is it possible that the object AppUser devlopper in Intervention doesnt refer the list of intervention in AppUser ? with joincolumn and jsonbackreference? i mean this won't create to me any problem but i just never seen an object doesnt refer another in other class(for this case : AppUser) , as i'm beginner with spring  .

Comment: I am not sure I understand now what do you need. Can you describe it without referring to existing code?

Comment: ofcours so : I want to know if is it normal declaring an object in a class with joinColumn("somthing") while it doesn't refer any  mapping in the second class to which this object belong  ?